# How to auto move a post different category in wordpress on a date?

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to auto move a post different category on future time? 
Example: Post1 in Category1 , i want to auto move to Category2 on 31.12.2012 00:00 time.
also Post2 in Category3 and i want to auto move it to Category4 on 31.12.2012 00:00 time.

How can i make it on wordpress? Any ideas? (By the way i tried to use content-scheduler plugin but it's only moving posts to only one category.I need to auto move posts to specific categories for every post.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this using the cron job feature.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpematico/

You would need to do a bit of research on finding the tables that need the work.